# Why is a Feistel Network able to both encrypt and decrypt just by using the round keys in a different order

Tags: feistel-network

Using a feistel network, to encrypt something you can just use the round keys. But to decrypt it, the same order of processes is applied, however the keys are used in reverse.

My question is: What makes this property of Feistel networks possible?

Answer (score 3):

In short because XOR is its own inverse operation. a XOR b XOR b is a again.

To decrypt an encrypted message we have to reverse the round function. For algorithms like AES (which is no Feistel network but a Substitution-permutation network, in short SPN) we have to reverse most operations like the MixColumn operation. This inversion is called InverseMixColumn. Theoretically we also have to do that for any Feistel network, but they nearly always use XOR as the combination of the one half with the changed other half. The inverse of XOR is again XOR, so we don't have to change it, but can just do the same again.

Take a look at a diagram of Feistel networks. Look at the output of the encryption scheme. Now try to reverse this - go back step by step. You can put one half again into the Round function, get and intermediate result and XOR this with the other half. Now you got back the input before this calculation. Repeat this until you are back at the first input which is your original plaintext. The round keys you used while doing this were the same as for the encryption, but in reversed order.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the structure of a 4 round block cipher. ($L$ and $R$ are named for left and right but obviously you could name them whatever you want. L/R, R/L, Up/Down, East/West, A/B...)

$(L_0, R_0) = \text{PlainText}$

Round 1:

> $L_1 = L_0 \oplus (F(R_0) \oplus \text{RoundKey}_1$
>
> $R_1 = R_0$

Round 2:

> $L_2 = L_1$
>
> $R_2 = R_1 \oplus (F(L_1) \oplus \text{RoundKey}_2$

Round 3:

> $L_3 = L_2 \oplus F(R_2) \space\oplus \text{RoundKey}_3$
>
> $R_3 = R_2$

Round 4:

> $L_4 = L_3$
>
> $R_4 = R_3 \oplus F(L_3) \space\oplus \text{RoundKey}_4$

$\text{CipherText} = (L_4, R_4)$

---

Basic Fiestel ciphers work on the left and right halves separately. A round either modifies $L$ or $R$ and the value it uses to change one half depends only on the value of the other half. That is, you define $F(x)$ (which does not need to be invertible). If instead you had $(x', y') = F(x, y)$ then to decrypt you would need its inverse, $F^{-1}(x, y)$.

Look at how values are updated each round. To decrypt you're given $\text{CipherText}$, so you know $L_4$ and $R_4$.

You try to undo one round at a time, so you want to find $(L_3, R_3)$ next.

One value, $L$, remains unchanged. (Note $L_3 = L_4$)

The other value you change by XORing a function of $L_3$ (or $L_4$) with the last round key.

With $L_3$ and $R_3$, you now have enough data to undo round 3. Then do the same with round 2 and round 1.

The $F$ function is unaware of both the round number, the round key, and the intermediate state. If you go through the step-by-step process to undo the encryption process it's clear why people say you can use the same algorithm with the keys in reverse order. However, depending on the number of rounds, you may need to swap the right and left halves.

Usually XOR is used (as opposed to add and subtract) because the inverse of $G(x) = x \oplus N$ is itself, $G^{-1}(x) = x \oplus N$.

If instead you used ordinary modular addition you need to replace $+$ with $-$ in your implementation. For extremely space constrained system where every extra byte of machine code matters* it makes sense to choose a Fiestel cipher using XOR. You optimize to minimize space as opposed to speed.

---

* And also you want to use a block cipher as opposed to a stream cipher or sponge construct. And you need to use the block cipher in forward and reverse mode. You don't need to use a block cipher in reverse for certain modes (like CTR mode), however.

SPN and ARX constructs have the "downside" that you need to implement forward and reverse operations, leading to up to double the amount of bytes of machine code. Again that might not matter.